# Will writing disk operations under linux affect CPU performance?

Tags: linux, io, filesystems

The linux disk writing operation must first write to the memory and then write to the disk at the appropriate time. Also, when writing to the disk the CPU can be freed for use by other processes while waiting for the disk to complete.

In this case, write disk operations should not affect the computing performance of Linux.Is this correct?

Comment: It depends. You have not provided enough details. Systems with DMA can offload to the DMA controller. Systems withh, say, software RAID need to calculate a CRC or similar code so some CPU time is used. Also see [How does linux file cache work?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+linux+file+cache+work%3F) Then try [How does linux file cache work dma?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+linux+file+cache+work+dma%3F)

Answer (score 0):

To release the CPU from performing write and read operations on peripherals the Direct Memory Access (DMA) is used. The DMA-Controller, assuming your Linux System has one, is instructed by the CPU to perform the Data transfer. So the CPU  needs to initiate the transfer. Additionally the DMA-Controller is working on a bus, that the rest of your system might also like to use. However, your CPU should not be affected much by a data-transfer.